# Not getting file through FileInputStream?

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, fileinputstream, filechannel

I am trying to check file position so that it would not be overwritten. For this purpose I have to use `FileInputStream` because it has a method `position()` that can be use with `FileChannel`. `BufferedReader` does not maintain position.

My code is:

```
FileChannel fc = null;
FileInputStream fis = null;      
int i=0;
long pos;
char c;
fis = new FileInputStream("File.txt");
   while((i=fis.read())!=-1)
                         {
                            fc = fis.getChannel();
                            pos = fc.position();
                            c = (char)i;
                            System.out.print("No of bytes read: "+pos);
                            System.out.println("; Char read: "+c);
                         }
```

I am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException`:

> /doneQuestionDetail.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory)

This error means it is not getting file from location because file doesn't exsist there and if I use `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("File.txt")));
```

It does not give any error in this line meaning file exists and `FileInputStream` is not getting file.

After searching I got to get location first and then give it to `FileInputStream`, then I changed code like:

```
String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                            File mFolder = new File(extr + "/imotax");
                            String s = "doneQuestionDetail.txt";
                            File f = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(), s);
                             fis = new FileInputStream(f);
```

Now I am getting an error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/imotax/File.txt: open
>   failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Hope for your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
                        + "/imotax");
dir.mkdirs();
File f= new File(dir, fileToCreate);
if(!f.exists()){
f.createNewFile();
}

fis = new FileInputStream(f);
```